# How to synchronize every pair of dynamically created inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating dynamically multiple elements and i want to synchronize specific ones. I write this code to give a view of my problem as simple as i can.

After creating input and append his value i want to have possibility to edit it every time i want. 
So if i create multiple iputs of id `input0,1,2 etc.` and change value of specific one i want to get this value in suitable input. I write function for 1 pair, How can i achieve that for every pair of dynamically created inputs?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 0;
  $('#add').hide();
  
  $('#generateInput').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<input name="input' + a + '">');
    $('#generateInput').toggle();
    $('#add').toggle();
  })
  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<input name="copyInput' + a + '" value="' + $('input[name="input' + a + '"]').val() + '"readonly="readonly"><br />');
    $('#add,#generateInput').toggle();
    a++;
  })
});

//how to make this for all created inputs?
$(document).on('keyup', '[name="input0"]', function() {
  $('[name="copyInput0"]').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divArea"></div>

<button id="generateInput">Generate</button>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the `onkeyup()` for each input you create and get the value inside that function.

```js
var a = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add').hide();
  $('#generateInput').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<input onkeyup="onKeyUp(this)" name="input' + a + '" index="' + a + '">');
    $('#generateInput').toggle();
    $('#add').toggle();
  })
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#divArea').append('<input name="copyInput' + a + '" value="' + $('input[name="input' + a + '"]').val() + '"readonly="readonly"><br />');
    $('#add,#generateInput').toggle();
    a++;
  })
});
//how to make this for all created inputs?
function onKeyUp(input) {
  $('input[name="copyInput' + $(input).attr('index') + '"]').val(input.value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="divArea">
</div>

<button id="generateInput">
    Generate
    </button>
<button id="add">
    Add
    </button>
```

Comment: but i dont want to get value of all inputs, i want to get value of `input0` to `copyInput0`, `input1` to `copyInput1` etc.

Comment: yes, once you click on Add, the new input is having the same value as left input

Comment: ok, but after that if i want to change value of `input0` i want this value in `copyInput0` like i create it for 1 pair of inputs i want this for every pair of created inputs

Comment: that's what i want, but could you describe this just a little? I dont understand how `$('input[name="copyInput' + $(input).attr('index') + '"]').val(input.value)` work

Comment: yep, the index is just a reference to `a` so that we can target the copy element as well. So, to do that, we add that index as an attribute to the first input.